# Merging results from Prediction to Original Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I have completed a machine learning algorithm that classifies categories from text. I am 99 percent done however i do now know to to merge my prediction results back to the original dataframe to see a print view of what i started with and what the prediction was.

## here is my code below.

```
#imports data from excel file and shows first 5 rows of data
file_name = r'C:\Users\aac1928\Documents\Machine Learning\Training        Data\RFP Training Data.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'

import pandas as pd
import numpy
import xlsxwriter
import sklearn

df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name,sheet_name=sheet)

#extracts specifics rows from data 
data = df.iloc[: , [0,2]]
print(data)

#Gets data ready for model
newdata = df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
newdata = newdata.rename(columns={'Label':'label'})
newdata = newdata.rename(columns={'RFP Question':'question'})
print(newdata)

# how to define X and yfor use with COUNTVECTORIZER
X = newdata.question
y = newdata.label
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

# split X and y into training and testing sets
X_train = X
y_train = y
X_test = newdata.question[:50]
y_test = newdata.label[:50]
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

# import and instantiate CountVectorizer (with the default parameters)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()

# equivalently: combine fit and transform into a single step
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)

# transform testing data (using fitted vocabulary) into a document-term matrix
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
X_test_dtm

# import and instantiate a logistic regression model
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# train the model using X_train_dtm
%time logreg.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

# make class predictions for X_test_dtm
y_pred_class = logreg.predict(X_test_dtm)
y_pred_class

# calculate predicted probabilities for X_test_dtm (well calibrated)
y_pred_prob = logreg.predict_proba(X_test_dtm)[:, 1]
y_pred_prob

# calculate accuracy
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)
```

## this is my new data added to make predictions from with the same length as the array

```
# split X and y into training and testing sets
X_train = X
y_train = y
X_testnew = dfpred.question
y_testnew = dfpred.label
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_testnew.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_testnew.shape)
```

(447,)
(168,)
(447,)
(168,)

```
# transform new testing data (using fitted vocabulary) into a document-term matrix
X_test_dtm_new = vect.transform(X_testnew)
X_test_dtm_new
```

<168x1382 sparse matrix of type ''
    with 2240 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

```
# make class predictions for new X_test_dtm
y_pred_class_new = nb.predict(X_test_dtm_new)
y_pred_class_new
```

array([ 3,  3, 19, 18,  5, 10, 10,  5, 19,  3,  3,  3,  5,  3,  3,  3,  3,
        9, 19,  5,  5, 10,  9,  5, 18, 19,  9,  9, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18,  4,
       18,  3,  9, 18, 19, 19, 18, 19,  5, 19, 19,  3,  3, 18, 18,  5, 18,
        3,  4,  5,  6,  4,  5, 19, 19,  5,  5, 19, 19,  4,  5, 18,  5,  5,
       19,  5, 18,  5, 19, 18, 19,  5,  7,  5,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10,  9,  9,
        5,  5,  5,  5,  3, 18,  4,  9,  5,  3,  6,  9, 18,  7,  5,  9,  5,
        5, 19,  5,  5, 19,  5,  6,  5,  5,  6,  9, 21, 10,  9, 18,  9,  9,
        3, 18,  5,  6, 18,  6,  3,  6,  5, 18,  6,  5, 18,  5,  6,  7,  7,
        5,  7, 19, 18,  6,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5, 19, 16,  5, 19,  5,  5,  5,
        5, 19,  5,  7, 19,  6,  7,  3, 18, 18, 18,  6, 19, 19,  7],
      dtype=int64)

```
# calculate predicted probabilities for X_test_dtm (well calibrated)
y_pred_prob_new = logreg.predict_proba(X_test_dtm_new)[:, 1]
y_pred_prob_new

df['prediction'] = pd.Series(y_pred_class_new)

dfout = pd.merge(dfpred,df['prediction'].dropna() .to_frame(),how = 'left',left_index = True,   right_index = True)
```

print(dfout)

I hope this helps I am trying to be as clear as possible

Comment: And what is the error? This often helps us diagnose your issue.

Comment: Please try to make the posted code as minimal as possible; arguably all these `print` statements have nothing to do with your issue (edited & removed)...

Comment: it was coming up with this message "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" so what I did was I changed your suggested to a panda series `df['prediction'] = pd.Series(y_pred_class)` which then allowed me to merge the series with the data frame `dfout = pd.merge(dfpred,df['prediction'].dropna() .to_frame(),how = 'left',left_index = True,   right_index = True)` **Please let me know what you think**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think since your predictions are just an array you'll be better off just using:

```
df['predictions'] = y_pred_class
```

Comment: it was coming up with this message "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" so what I did was I changed your suggested to a panda series `df['prediction'] = pd.Series(y_pred_class)` which then allowed me to merge the series with the data frame `dfout = pd.merge(dfpred,df['prediction'].dropna() .to_frame(),how = 'left',left_index = True,   right_index = True)` **Please let me know what you think**

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your predictions array is shorter than your original `df` because you split into training and test sets.

Your `X_test` array you define as `newdata.question[:50]` which seems like you are getting the last 50 rows of that column.

What I would do is create a prediction_df that is the same length as your prediction array. In your case the rows you need are the last 50 rows of your original df.

```
prediction_df = df.iloc[:50]
prediction_df['predictions'] = y_pred_class
```

Just make sure that your prediction_df rows match up with the rows you used to make `X_test`!

Comment: thanks!! yes I figured that out. I wanted to know if my new was was correct. please read the revised post and my other comments!!